# RHEL : Certificate Import : Keystore error : Signed Fields invalid

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm configuring tomcat to use SSL/TLS1.2.

1. So I started with setting up a keystore

'keytool -genkey -keysize 2048 -keying RSA -alias hostname -keystore tomcat.jks'

I provided the required details and passcode to create the keystore.

2. I changed the keystore to pcks12

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tomcat.jks -destkeystore tomcat.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
3. Generated the certificate signing request

   'keytool –keystore tomcat.p12 –certreq –alias hostname –keyalg rsa –file tomcat.csr'
4. Imported the ssl certificate with passcode

   keytool -importcert -file sslcert.pfx -alias hostname -keystore tomcat.p12 -storepass Xxxxxxxx

During the 4th step I got the error "keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Signed fields invalid". The ssl certificate has its own password but not sure where the parsing error is. Any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the pfx certificate into .pem fixed the issue. The certificate was converted using the below

```
openssl pkcs12 -in sslcert.pfx -out sslcert.pem -nodes
```